# Does RTS -T flag disable GHC optimization

Tags: haskell, ghc

It's known that profiling will turn off any optimization by GHC. Does that also happen when using RTS -T flag to obtain GC stats?

Comment: Detailed profiling doesn't turn off optimization, but each interferes with the other. RTS flags never affect optimization directly because they are passed to a program after it's been compiled.

Comment: @dfeuer you should post that as the answer :-)

Comment: @dfeuer indeed. I'll accept once you post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detailed profiling doesn't turn off optimization, but each interferes with the other. Notably, inlining wreaks havoc on cost-center profiling, since the cost of inlined functions is assigned to their called.

RTS flags never affect optimization directly because they are passed to a program after it's been compiled. Of course RTS flags can and often do affect *performance* by changing the behavior of the garbage collector, collecting information about the program for profiling, etc.